# Cannot get data from feig UHF Reader using TCPListener

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, rfid, tcplistener

I have to write an application for gate monitoring with Feig UHF RFID Reader(LMR2500-B).Since the reader is intended for gate monitoring, I also need to listen every time from the reader. I have tried to set Host Mode in the reader's configuration.I can get data from the reader with ISO Command of Feig reader.But, with host mode, EAS Alarm is not working properly. So,I need to set the reader as Buffered Read Mode to trigger EAS Alarm properly.When I set the reader as Buffered Read Mode,then ISO Command of feig reader cannot be used.So,I tried to use TCPListener,listen to the reader and tried to get data whenever the reader detect the tag.However, I cannot get any data from the reader. As I know TCPListener need to listen and can get data only when tcpclient send data, what configuration do i need to set on the reader to act as tcpclient? Is there any other ways to get data from my application whenever the reader detect the data and the reader is still in buffered read mode.If my understanding miss something,please kindly correct me... Please help me... Thanks..

Comment: I belive in host mode you control everything manually. So once you detected a tag its your duty to trigger alarm by calling appropriate command. You can try find it using ISOStart

Comment: If you are not on mono/win IoT, then your best choice is feig native c# wrapper. It has its own drawbacks but it's much easier to start with this wrapper rather then tcplistner